# Cumulative function for a specific range of values

Tags: r, cumsum

I have a table with a column "Age" that has a values from 1 to 10, and a column "Population" that has values specified for each of the "age" values. I want to generate a cumulative function for population such that resultant values start from ages at least 1 and above, 2 and above, and so on. I mean, the resultant array should be (203,180..and so on). Any help would be appreciated!

```
Age  Population Withdrawn
1     23         3
2     12         2
3     32         2
4     33         3
5     15         4 
6     10         1
7     19         2
8     18         3
9     19         1
10    22         5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cumsum` and `rev`:

```
df$sum_above <- rev(cumsum(rev(df$Population)))
```

The result:

```
> df
   Age Population sum_above
1    1         23       203
2    2         12       180
3    3         32       168
4    4         33       136
5    5         15       103
6    6         10        88
7    7         19        78
8    8         18        59
9    9         19        41
10  10         22        22
```

Comment: IMO the OP wants : `rev(cumsum(rev(df$Population)))`

Comment: @digEmAll thank you, you are right; I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks! But it worked when the 'df$' within the brackets was removed.
As you can see in the original question, I have added another column "Withdrawn". I would want to modify the previous answer, rev(cumsum..), in such a way the values represent cumulative proportions of withdrawn kids. Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Simos you mean `df$sum_withdrawn <- cumsum(df$Withdrawn)`?